How to disable some_imported_function not found when imported file only has export * from child file
eslint throws exported functions not found in '../src/scripts/index.js' where index.js export * from child js file.
So it's true index.js does not have those functions but in reality the app works because index.js can import those functions from the child js files with export * from child.js.
